# How do you reference the index of the column in a for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

Hi sorry I'm new to Pandas. I was wondering how to input the index of whatever column I am trying to perform the function on. I tried `df[column].index` but I keep getting `IndexError` on those lines I use it in.

For context I am trying to find the index at which a certain value (-10) is passed for each column which is `cd`. Then I have to interpolate it to find the exact value at which -10 occurs which is `cd10`.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    cd = HERdf.loc[df.iloc[: , df[column].index] <= -10].index[0]
    cd10 = np.interp(x = -10 , xp = df.iloc[cd-1:cd+2 , df[column].index] , fp = df.iloc[cd-1:cd+2 , 0] )
    print (cd10)
```

Comment: Can you provide part of your data frame (or pseudo data frame) and your desired output? Otherwise I have to guess what you are looking for.

Comment: @ko3 
I'll put 1 instead of `df[column].index` to give an example. For now it'll give the same 3 values as I currently only have 3 columns to work on. 
-0.42188000000000014
-0.42188000000000014
-0.42188000000000014

Comment: Try `df.columns.tolist().index(column)` instead of `df[column].index`

Comment: @ko3 The 'dataframe' is maybe col1: 1 2 3 col2: -9 -10.1 -10.2 and so on. I am trying to find the exact value of col1 where itll give me exactly- 10 from col2.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve. Does my answer help somehow? If not, please make your question more precise and include an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your code as I do not fully understand how your dataframe is structured and I did not fully understand the interpolation part but I would try to suggest a solution to your problem purely from your description.

From the description I guess that you want to get the numeric index of a column from column name. Please correct me if I am wrong and the interpolation is a significant part of the question.

You can do it by converting the column index of the dataframe to a list.

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    column_index = df.columns.tolist().index(column)
    print(f'column index of {column} is {column_index}')
```

Another option which looks more pythonic to me would be to enumerate the columns:

```
for column_index, column in enumerate(df.columns[1:], start=1):
    print(f'column index of {column} is {column_index}')
```